# Convert 24 hour time to 12 hour AM/PM in a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

My objective is to convert a mySQL database item now in a 24-hour time format to a 12-hour AM/PM format using the PHP that queries and adapts the data for use in a calendar.

Current mySQL item example:

```
(Name) start_time | (Type) varchar(20) | (Collation) utf8_general_ci |
(Null) No | (Default) None
```

Current database PHP query/array item:

```
$timetable->start_time  = $db_timetable['start_time'];
```

Returns the database content as entered, i.e.: 13:30

**Proposed database PHP query/array item:**

```
$timetable->start_time  = DATE_FORMAT($date,
'%r'($db_timetable['start_time']));
```

Want it to be converted to: 1:30 PM

I’ve tried numerous variations on the proposed query, but with no luck. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: it's not a full date, so you can't use date functions, you can do a workaround, explode the value using ':' separator, then the value in index 0 you can check if lower than 12 then - from 24 and use pm otherwise use am.

Comment: This isn't valid PHP code. It's hard to tell what you're even intending here. Is that the PHP [`date_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) function? If so, why is it all upper-case?

Comment: If the goal is to use the MySQL DATE_FORMAT that needs to be in the query, not where you are accessing the results of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'g': 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros

'i': Minutes with leading zeros

'a': Lowercase Ante meridiem and Post meridiem

This code will output the time in the format h:mm AM/PM, for example: 1:30 PM:

```
$timetable->start_time = date('g:i A', strtotime($db_timetable['start_time']));
```